# Redirect in logout action not refreshing the main route child outlet index page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is my `router` setup:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <MainHeader />, // wraps around all the child routes below
      errorElement: <Error />, // displays this page upon an error
      id: "root",
      loader: tokenLoader,
      action: actionLogin(ctx),
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <Home {...{ filmsPerPage }} />,
          loader: () => loaderHome(filmsPerPage),
        }, // index route ./
        {
          path: "filmview/:filmid",
          id: "filmview",
          loader: loaderFilmView,
          children: [
            { index: true, element: <FilmView />, action: actionFilmDelete },
          ],
        },
        { path: "logout", action: actionLogout(ctx) },
      ],
    },
    { path: "/signup", element: <SignUp /> },
  ]);
```

This is my `MainHeader.js`

```
const MainHeader=(props)=>{     
    return(
        <>
        .........

        {/* Outlet is the place where the child routes should be rendered to, i.e. all the 
        children components in App.js */}
        <Outlet/>

        <footer>
            ...........
        </footer>
        </>
    );
}
```

This is my `Logout.js`

```
export const action=(ctx)=>()=>{
  // clear local storage --> working 
  // clear cookies --> working 
  // clear context --> working 

  return redirect('/'); <-- this doesn't seem to work for /
}
```

I'm accessing the logout in a useEffect socket.on connection (or any useEffect) as follows:

```
if(condition) submit(null,{action:'/logout', method:'post'})
```

It's accessing the logout and logging out the user (which is working) but the redirect doesn't seem to work; it's not fully carrying me back to home if I'm on another page. e.g. If I'm on the home page and logs out it works. But if I'm on the `filmview` page and click `logout`, the main header logs out and the URL changes to `home` but the body still shows the previous film view outlet child page content.

I don't know if it's not loading the outlet/child because the URL is changing to `/`. If I change `Logout.js` to `redirect('/signup')` it's working:

```
export const action=(ctx)=>()=>{
  .........    
  return redirect('/signup'); <-- this is working, it goes to signup page after logout
}
```

But isn't working with `redirect('/')`. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem